# How to increase FOV in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

How can I increase **FOV** (Field Of View) on **Borderlands** for PC?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1463861:

```
To adjust FOV (Field of View):
-----------------------------
Within WillowInput.ini:
Below the chunk of bindings on the first section/paragraph, add the following:

Bindings=(Name="F10",Command="FOV 90",Control=False,Shift=False,Alt=False)
Bindings=(Name="F11",Command="FOV 110",Control=False,Shift=False,Alt=False)

You can change the keys (F10 and F11) to whatever you'd like, as well as the FOV values.
```

Comment: just tried, it works perfectly!

Comment: Where can i find this file WillowInput.ini?

Comment: USER NAME\Documents\My Games\Borderlands\WillowGame\Config

Comment: For some reason F10/F11 didn't work right for me, so I used NumPadOne, NumPadTwo, etc. instead. I generally prefer 100 or 110, although when you sprint the FOV goes ridiculously high.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not affiliated with the person who made this, [but here's a really good config editor (Borderlands Config Tool / Configuration Editor)](https://web.archive.org/web/20091216133311/http://gbxforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=85874) that allows you to change the FOV, among other handy stuff. (download mirror sites of current latest version, v2.1.4:  [[1]](http://www.mediafire.com/download/in2oo6tkddo0y54/Borderlands+Config+Editor+v2.1.4.exe) [[2]](http://www.2shared.com/file/_EOeFcUN/Borderlands_Config_Editor_v214.html))

[image: Borderlands Config Tool / Configuration Editor - increase FOV (Field Of View)]

Answer (score 3):

Borderlands: GOTY Enhanced added in an FOV slider that goes from 60 to 120, defaulting to 75.

[image: Borderlands GOTY Video options]

Owners of Borderlands on Steam were given a free copy of the new edition which appears as a separate entry in their Steam library.  This version is also being sold on Xbox One and PS4.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great page of [PC Tweaks](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks) on the [Borderlands Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com) that includes instructions for this, as well as a lot of other useful tweaks.

The instructions for changing FOV are [here](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Tweaks#Adjust_FOV_.28Field_of_View.29), also take note of the section below it that explains how to bind them to your movement keys. This is quite useful because you don't have to remember to manually hit a dedicated key like F11 every time you get out of a vehicle or stop sprinting (both of which change your FOV).