# Has Borderlands recently made it so you can't change Field of View?

Tags: borderlands

I reinstalled Borderlands last night from Steam and went through the usual [tweaks](http://gbxforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=79043) to make it more like a PC game. I even did something similar to the FOV increase described in [this g.se question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/702/how-to-increase-fov-in-borderlands), but I still can't change my FOV. Just to make sure that my WillowInput.ini file was working, I changed the mouse sensitivity, and that change stuck.

Has something happened recently where changing the FOV no longer works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Borderlands has not recently made it so you can't change your field of view. The culprit was my bindings being placed in the wrong section of the `WillowInput.ini` file. The [linked question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/702/how-to-increase-fov-in-borderlands) doesn't say that the bindings must be placed in the `[WillowGame.WillowPlayerInput]` section of the `WillowInput.ini` file.